# Fetching data from multiple tables and displaying them as per date

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have got three different table where i am storing balance of a user. so what i need is to have a proper statement of his balance according to the date.
Is it possible to get the values on three different tables and to show them as one as per the date?
Eg:

```
Table 1 
Member = member 1
date = 1 JULY 2016
Amount = 2000

Table 2
Member = member 1
date = 5 JULY 2016
Amount = 5000

Table 3
Member = member 1
date = 10 JULY 2016
Amount = 10000

So the output should be:
Member       Date         Amount
Member 1     01/07/2016    2000
Member 1     05/07/2016    5000
Member 1     10/07/2016    10000
```

Comment: is every "member" guaranteed to have a row in every table? are there members that could be missing from all 3 tables? could you improve the question with some sort of schema definition?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Table1
union all 
select * from Table2
union all 
select * from Table3
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your problem correctly  **union all** funtion will do

```
 select Member,Date,Amount from Table1
    union all
    select Member,Date,Amount from Table2
    union all
    select Member,Date,Amount from Table3
```

Answer (score 0):

using sql joins will help you solving ur problem you can learn about sql joins through:-http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql_certificate/get_data_from_multiple_tables.htm